# Regex for url resource part

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, url

**Context**

I have code that takes an url path and replaces path params with '*'. 
All my urls follow [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#urls) naming convention.
All valid url resource parts follow next rules:

- *Member names SHOULD start and end with the characters “a-z” (U+0061
  to U+007A)*
- *Member names SHOULD contain only the characters “a-z”
  (U+0061 to U+007A),   “0-9” (U+0030 to U+0039), and the hyphen minus
  (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, “-“)   as separator between multiple words.*

The pass param usually is an id (number, uuid, guid, etc).

Here are several examples of transformations:

- `/user/e09e4f9f-cfcd-4a23-a88f-b9f2f265167f/info -> /user/*/info`
- `/user/e09e4f9f-cfcd-4a23-a88f-b9f2f265167f -> /user/*`
- `/user/1 -> /user/*`

**What I have**

`/^[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z]$/`

The issues is that it doesn't handle uuid as a path param.

Here is my function that parses the url (sorry don't have time to create a jsfiddle):

```
const escapeResourcePathParameters = resource => resource
  .substr(resource.startsWith('/') ? 1 : 0)
  .split('/')
  .reduce((url, member) => {
     const match = member.match(REGEX.JSONAPI_RESOURCE_MEMBER);

     const part = match
         ? member
         : '*';

     return `${url}/${part}`;
}, '');
```

**Questions**

I need a regex that follows the rules above and works for the examples above.

**UPD:**
I've added my function that I use to parse urls. To test your regex, just replace it with `REGEX.JSONAPI_RESOURCE_MEMBER` and pass the url like
`/user/e09e4f9f-cfcd-4a23-a88f-b9f2f265167f/info`, it should return `/user/*/info`

Comment: what is "path param" (that need to be replaced by '*') - how to 'recognize it' ?

Comment: how does `1` in `/user/1` comply to the `Member names SHOULD start and end with the characters “a-z”` ?

Comment: @MatusDubrava Because `1` in this case is a parameter not a member of the API.

Comment: @MatusDubrava it doesn't cause, 1 is a path parameter, it shouldn't follow the rules, and I need to replace it

Comment: That's like the issue, I need to find resource parts that are not follow the rules and replace them

Comment: Most likely you need to remove the anchors `^` and `$` from your regex. Also escape the slash character. Try `\/[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z]*\/`

Comment: @Sergio nope, doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

i am guessing you are looking for a regex to capture the UUID :

this should be working in javascript :

```
/[a-z][a-z0-9]+[-]+[a-z0-9-]+[a-z]/
```

I suppose a UUID Should have at least two words, so at least one "-"

```js
let a = "/user/e09e4f9f-cfcd-4a23-a88a/info"

const match = a.match(/[a-z][a-z0-9]+[-]+[a-z0-9-]+[a-z]/)

console.log(match[0])
```

So for your code, it should be something like

```
 const escapeResourcePathParameters = resource => resource
  .substr(resource.startsWith('/') ? 1 : 0)
  .split('/')
  .reduce((url, member) => {
    // with  REGEX.JSONAPI_RESOURCE_MEMBER = /[a-z][a-z0-9]*[-]+[a-z0-9-]+[a-z]/
    return `${url}/${member.replace(REGEX.JSONAPI_RESOURCE_MEMBER, '*')}`;

 }, '');
```

Comment: I don;t think so, the `user` part is just an example, it can be
`/info/user/1/list/5`

Comment: and how .* handles the rules described above?

Comment: >I suppose a UUID Should have at least two words, so at least one "-"
correct, but this doesn't work, I'll share a bit of code that parses the url

Answer (score 0):

You could use look-arounds:

[`(?<=\/)[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z](?=\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/wexrjv/1)

As noted in my comment, no need to use the anchors `^` nor `$`. Also escape slash `\/`. The regex wil match the pattern `[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z]` only when surrounded by slashes.

```
/user/e09e4f9f-cfcd-4a23-a88f-b9f2f265167f/info # result:  /*/*/info
/user/e09e4f9f-cfcd-4a23-a88f-b9f2f265167f      # result:  /*/e09e4f9f-cfcd-4a23-a88f-b9f2f265167f
/user/1                                         # result: /*/1
```

To match UUIDs use:

[`(?<=\/)[a-z0-9-]{8}-(?:[a-z0-9-]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9-]{12}(?=\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/wexrjv/2)

The UUID format is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format